# Connection between Web tier and the EJB3 beans

Tags: netbeans, struts2, ejb-3.0

I have created an WebApplication(Struts2) an an EJB module in netbeans. How can I access the beans from the WebApplication. How can I make the beans available in the web tier. If the answer is application-client.xml and jndi.properties please let me know how to configure them.

Comment: Use ejb3.1, not 3.0... and if you are not interested in IoC, do a simple lookup.

Comment: You can simply use `jndi` lookup and locate your ejbs.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. But I want to use annotation as this is the new feature added in EJB3. Please suggest.